# Error in .getModisList(x = xx, h = h, v = v, dates = dates, opt = opt, : No available data for the selected dates

Tags: r, modis

I have a problem using ModisDownload from RTS Package on R, i always have the same error using ModisDownload or getMODIS functions :

```
Error in .getModisList(x = xx, h = h, v = v, dates = dates, opt = opt,  : No available data for the selected dates
```

Here is my code :

```
library(rts)
x = "MOD14A1"
ModisDownload(x=x,h=c(17,18),v=c(4,5),dates='2011.05.01',mosaic=F,proj=F)
```

This is the basic code from RTS documentation. I used different dates or products like MOD09GA (which one i have to use for my research project) and current dates like 2018.04.08

Comment: Hi! Not sure what's happening. Also had the same problem for this and other products and different dates too. Strongly recommend that you check this R package for MODIS data processing - MODIStsp: https://github.com/lbusett/MODIStsp | http://lbusett.github.io/MODIStsp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, I used Modis library but I had to first install gdal and MRT and link these libraries on my global variable environment. It works well.

Example:

```
library(MODIS)

Sys.setenv(MRT_DATA_DIR  = "/Path/To/MRT/data",
           MRT_HOME = "/Path/To/MRT/bin",
           PATH="/Path/To/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs")

getHdf(product = "MOD09A1", begin = "2016.06.01",end = "2017.11.30",
       tileH = 11, tileV = 12, quiet = 0)
```

Link to GDAL : https://gdal.gloobe.org/install.html
Link to MRT : https://www.romerostories.com/single-post/2017/12/22/Modis-Reprojection-Tool-MRT---Installation-tutorial

You can add MRT to your global variable, but it is not necessary to use getHdf, your just need to install GDAL and verify with `MODISoptions()`if MODIS find your libraries.

Comment: can you extend your answer on how you used "modis library"?